# Intersection of a raster and polygon in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, arcgis-10.3, intersect

I have two data sets one raster and one polygon. I am interested to see learning the area where the two overlap. I was thinking that I could use the intersect function, but since one of the layers are a raster that will not work.

Is there another way for me to compute the area of the overlying areas?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is to clip raster by the polygon, to do that go to Data management toolbox -> Raster tools -> Raster Processing toolbox -> use the Clip tool found in the Analysis toolbox. You have the ability to use the selected features as the clipping extent. If a feature within the feature class is selected, and "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry" is checked, the raster image will be clipped based on the polygon extent.

Check [this help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm) for more info.

Comment: I have tried to use clip but it never executes. I waited 5 hours yesterday and then left it overnight running, and nothing has happened. I'm not sure what the issue is because it never gets an error message it just never performs the task.

Comment: Could you please show us the raster image and the polygon(s) overlaying  it? A screenshot of the data will help us to understand the situation.